# Bootstrap Dropdown - Onclick menu items, scorll to last submenu item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Dropdowns.

When I click on main menu "**Has Sub Menu**" list item, children of this list has to be Toggle. Till here it is working fine...

But how can I do: If I click on **Has Sub Menu** `<li>` I have to see all the submenu items without scorll to down... that means, my scorll should go the end of last sub menu item...

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0vjhaazv/8/)

> **jQuery**

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('ul.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.submenu').toggle();
});
```

> **HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group open" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li class="pd-dropdown">

                <a href="#" class="test">Has Sub Menu
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this jquery

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
console.log("gdfg");
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').scrollTop(500);
});
```

This is a **[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/0vjhaazv/9/)**

Comment: Excellent @shri... working like a Champ... Thanks for your effort... Voting Up and Accepting your Answer... Keep up the Good Work....

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, this is what's stopping them all showing

```
.dropdown-menu{ max-height:250px; overflow:auto; }
```

If you want to see them all then change it to this:

```
.dropdown-menu{ overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: :)... I want to set max-height... because it is hamburger menu which has more than 80 elements which I can't give full height of the menu...

Comment: it has to have max-height property with scrollbar... if I click on Menu which has submenu.. my scrollbar should go to the end of submenu items.